# Can I replace message in my commit message(git)?

Tags: git, git-commit, githooks, python-re

I used commit-msg hook in git to check if my commit are right and want to automatically replace the BugID with the Bug Address. But it seems like it can only add one more row at the bottom of the commit message instead of replacing the original lines. Is there any way I can make it work?
my commit template is

```
Branch:
BugId:
Description:
```

Here's my code:

```
with open(sys.argv[1],r+) as fp:
    lines=fp.readlines()
    for line in lines:
        if line[0]=="#":
            continue
        line=line.strip()
        for l in l.split('/n'):
            if not l.split(":")[-1]:
                print(l,"is empty")
                sys.exit(1)
            if l.startswith("Bug"):
                fp.write(l.replace(l.split(":")[-1],"http:bugs.xxxxxxxxx")
sys.exit(0)
```

Comment: What is `l` in the expression `l.split('/n')`?

Comment: I'm afraid your Python code is terrible and wrong here. :-) Start by opening the file and reading it (as you do) but then *seek back to the beginning* before trying to write the file, and make sure you write every line you want to have appear *in* the file. Fix the bug @mkrieger1 noted and the other obvious bugs (there's nothing to split yet, you already split by lines), etc. This seems to be better phrased as a question about how to write the code you want in whatever language you want to write it...

Comment: This strikes me as something that could be a two-line readable bash script.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example from Gerrit that adds "Change-Id: ...." line to each commit if it doesn't exist

Of course, its not Python, but I think you can borrow an idea from there

```
#!/bin/sh
# From Gerrit Code Review 2.16.2
#
# Part of Gerrit Code Review (https://www.gerritcodereview.com/)
#
# Copyright (C) 2009 The Android Open Source Project
#
# Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
# you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
# You may obtain a copy of the License at
#
# http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
#
# Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
# distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
# WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
# See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
# limitations under the License.

# avoid [[ which is not POSIX sh.
if test "$#" != 1 ; then
  echo "$0 requires an argument."
  exit 1
fi

if test ! -f "$1" ; then
  echo "file does not exist: $1"
  exit 1
fi

if test ! -s "$1" ; then
  echo "file is empty: $1"
  exit 1
fi

# $RANDOM will be undefined if not using bash, so don't use set -u
random=$( (whoami ; hostname ; date; cat $1 ; echo $RANDOM) | git hash-object --stdin)
dest="$1.tmp.${random}"

# Avoid the --in-place option which only appeared in Git 2.8
# Avoid the --if-exists option which only appeared in Git 2.15
cat "$1" \
  | git -c trailer.ifexists=doNothing interpret-trailers --trailer "Change-Id: I${random}" > "${dest}" \
  && mv "${dest}" "$1"
```

Note the last lines of the script: it creates a `dest`, then prints the message and adds "Change-Id" if it doesn't exist. Then it moves the temp dest to actually become a message. Job done.

I'm not a really profficient in git hooks but this one should be in the file named `.git/hooks/commit-msg` so I believe this is what you need